# SQL/JPQL select where less than or equal

Tags: sql, jpql

I'm writing a booking system for cars, and I want to create a query that returns all Cars depending on these factors, here's my code:

```
SELECT * FROM Car WHERE regNbr NOT LIKE 
(SELECT regNbr FROM Booking WHERE (startDate <= '20160422' AND endDate >= '20160422')
OR startDate <= '20160423' AND endDate >= '20160423')
AND model LIKE '%%'AND color LIKE '%%'
AND model LIKE (SELECT name FROM Model WHERE brand LIKE '%%' 
AND price <= 2000 AND seats >= 1 )
AND address LIKE (SELECT address FROM Garage WHERE address LIKE '%Malmö%')
```

and this is the error message I get:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= 
or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

on a sidenote would I use NativeNamedQuery or NamedQuery in JPQL for this?

Comment: Start with replacing `LIKE (SELECT..` with ` IN (SELECT...`. Then check the AND/OR date conditions for missing brackets